# Problems with PHPDOCX Charts & Images

Tags: php, xslt, php-ziparchive, phpdocx

Basically I'm using phpdocx on IIS 7.0 (PHP 5.2.14 FastCGI installed).

My problem is that when I run even the given examples in the installation of PHPDOCX, the tables and text works, however the charts and images do not appear in the document.

I was wondering if this had something to do with the requisites ZipArchive & XSL?  I have a "php_zip.dll" enabled in my php extensions and my php.ini file.

However I have not been able to find any mention of XSL/XSLT in my php.ini or php extensions settings.

Is this my problem, and if so how would I go about installing it?

Thanks.

Comment: The generated document was blank in both Word 2010 and 2007, so i'm fairly certain this isn't an issue with the software in my current version in word.

Comment: I had thought this might be a permissions issue, but I have also ruled this out.  Documents with tables can be produced but no charts as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

in your `php.ini`

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php

Comment: I've added the extension, but I checked my PHP/ext folder and the .dll doesn't seem to be there!

Is there anywhere reliable where I can download it from for my version of PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: Download php-5.2.14-Win32-VC6-x86.zip from here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/ and look in the "ext" folder

Comment: Hey,

This didn't fix my problem :(  Thanks for the help though.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried another example and received the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found.

I shall continue to work at it - I think you have pointed me on the right track so thank you.  If i get it fixed I will document and accept your answer above.

Comment: Sure, you can verify that the extension is loading using "phpinfo()" in a test page.

Comment: There is no mention of XSL in the phpinfo() output, I can verify that I've followed your instructions to the letter though.  I've also restarted the website, and refreshed my phpinfo() a few times.

Comment: If you don't have any mention of libxslt in phpinfo() output then the xsl.dll did not load. Have you checked the php error logs? Set display_startup_errors and display_startup to 1 and see what prints in the error log.

Comment: [20-Mar-2012 16:53:33] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xsl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0 - I can verify that the file is in this location.

Comment: Did you move/copy the php_xsl.dll file from php-5.2.14-Win32-VC6-x86.zip into C:\Program Files\PHP\ext ?

Comment: Yes I've done this.  Going to attempt a restart on the off chance that works.

Comment: There is a php configuration file in my C:\Windows directory.  I uncommented the "extension=php_xsl.php" & "extension=php_zip.php" just to be sure.  Same problem.

Comment: phpinfo will tell you which configuration file is loading. Also, extension=php_xsl.php should be extension=php_xsl.dll

Comment: Sorry that was a mistype, I meant to type .dll ^^

My Configuration file (php.ini) path is C:\Windows

My loaded Configuration file is C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini

Comment: I replaced the php_xsl.dll with the "NTS" version at the archives link you gave me and some more of the examples worked!

The charts still aren't showing but it's a step in the right direction!  Thank you for your help! :)